# Summing and counting across multiple tables in SQL

Tags: sql, db2-luw

I have 3 tables from which I need to select and summarize data.

```
Table: IDEA  
REFERENCE SL   
128       SL1  
200       SL1  
201       SL2  
205       SL3 



Table: ACCT1  
IDEA_REF  ACCTS  
128       5  
128       2  
200       3  
205       4  

Table: ACCT2  
IDEA_REF  ACCTS  
201       3  
205       4 
205       3
```

What I need to do is pull a summary sorted by SL with the totals from the ACCTS field of both tables.

Here is the SQL I am using so far:

```
SELECT I.SL AS SL, COUNT(DISTINCT I.REFERENCE) AS NO,  
    SUM(CASE WHEN A1.IDEA_REF=I.REFERENCE THEN A1.ACCTS ELSE 0 END) AS ACCT1,  
    SUM(CASE WHEN A2.IDEA_REF=I.REFERENCE THEN A2.ACCTS ELSE 0 END) AS ACCT2  
    FROM IDEA I  
    LEFT JOIN ACCT1 A1 ON A1.IDEA_REF=I.REFERENCE  
    LEFT JOIN ACCT2 A2 ON A2.IDEA_REF=I.REFERENCE  
    WHERE A2.IDEA_REF IN I.REFERENCE OR A1.IDEA_REF IN I.REFERENCE  
    GROUP BY I.SL
```

The problem I am finding is when there are multiple values in the ACCT1 and ACCT2 tables with reference to the IDEA table. Here are the results from this query:

```
SL  NO  ACCT1  ACCT2  
SL1 2   10      0  
SL2 1    0      3  
SL3 1    8      7
```

The SL3 line adds the ACCT1 and ACCT2 values two times. I can't seem to find the right way to add them the appropriate number of times.

The desired output is:

```
SL   NO   ACCT1  ACCT2
SL1  2    10     0  
SL2  1     0     3  
SL3  1     4     7
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: is 2 reference entries for SL1 in idea table is correct in first place

Comment: Yes, in my actual tables, there are other columns with unique data.

Comment: what dbms system are you using? You tagged with three different ones, where the syntax can be somewhat different between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You hare asking for three separate aggregates, but you're trying to compute them all in a single query.

To get your `NO` (count of distinct items) you can do

```
SELECT SL,
       COUNT(*) AS NO
  FROM IDEA
 GROUP BY SL
```

To get your `ACCT1` item you can do:

```
SELECT SL,
       SUM(ACCTS) AS ACCT1
  FROM IDEA
  JOIN ACCT1 ON IDEA.REFERENCE = ACCT1.IDEA_REF
GROUP BY SL
```

In like manner you can get `ACCT2`

```
SELECT SL,
       SUM(ACCTS) AS ACCT2
  FROM IDEA
  JOIN ACCT2 ON IDEA.REFERENCE = ACCT2.IDEA_REF
GROUP BY SL
```

Then, you need to join all these aggregate queries together on SL to get your result set. Because you have missing entries in some of the aggregates, you need the `LEFT` in `LEFT JOIN` and the `COALESCE()` items.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/63aa1/1)

Here's the over all query

```
SELECT Q.SL, NO, 
       COALESCE(ACCT1,0) AS ACCT1, 
       COALESCE(ACCT2,0) AS ACCT2
  FROM (
        SELECT SL,
               COUNT(*) AS NO
          FROM IDEA
          GROUP BY SL
       ) Q
   LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT SL,
                 SUM(ACCTS) AS ACCT1
            FROM IDEA
            JOIN ACCT1 ON IDEA.REFERENCE = ACCT1.IDEA_REF
           GROUP BY SL
        ) R ON Q.SL = R.SL
   LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT SL,
                   SUM(ACCTS) AS ACCT2
              FROM IDEA
              JOIN ACCT2 ON IDEA.REFERENCE = ACCT2.IDEA_REF
            GROUP BY SL
         ) S ON Q.SL = S.SL
```

[The result is what you are looking for](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/63aa1/1/0):

```
|  SL | NO | ACCT1 | ACCT2 |
|-----|----|-------|-------|
| SL1 |  2 |    10 |     0 |
| SL2 |  1 |     0 |     3 |
| SL3 |  1 |     4 |     7 |
```

See how this works? You have to do each aggregate separately.

If you're using a DBMS that doesn't know the `JOIN ... USING()` syntax, put in  `ON Q.SL = R.SL`  or the appropriate `ON` clause instead.  See the edit, and see this fiddle:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/63aa1/3/0

Comment: Now my issue is using this query on DB2. I made an error on the original tags, by staging MySQL. I'm getting SQL0104N An unexpected token "USING" was found following "_REF GROUP BY SL ) R". I suspect I need to make a slight change for DB2 versus MySQL, but I'm not skilled enough to know what that is.

Comment: Switch the `USING` clause for an `ON` meaning the same thing. See my edit.

Comment: Also, use `COALESCE()` in place of `IFNULL()`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a subquery will outperform count distinct, also I should avoid multiple joins on the same table

```
SELECT
     i.SL,
     COUNT(DISTINCT i.SL) NO,
     COALESCE(SUM(a.sum1), 0) act1,
     COALESCE(SUM(b.sum2), 0) act2
FROM
     IDEA i
LEFT JOIN
     (
     SELECT
         IDEA_REF,
         SUM(ACCTS) sum1
     FROM
         ACCT1
     GROUP BY IDEA_REF
     ) a
     ON i.REFERENCE = a.IDEA_REF
LEFT JOIN
     (
     SELECT
         IDEA_REF,
         SUM(ACCTS) sum2
     FROM
         ACCT2
     GROUP BY IDEA_REF
     ) b
     ON i.REFERENCE = b.IDEA_REF
GROUP BY i.SL
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0f97f4/10)

The results are the same but less table scans

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the result by using UNION ALL

```
SELECT 
    COMB.SL AS SL, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT COMB.REFERENCE) AS NO, 
    sum(T1) as ACCT1, 
    sum(T2) ACCT2
FROM (
    SELECT 
        I.*,A1.ACCTS as t1,0 as t2
    FROM 
        IDEA I  
    LEFT JOIN 
        ACCT1 A1 ON A1.IDEA_REF=I.REFERENCE  
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        I.*,0 as t1,A2.ACCTS as t2
    FROM 
        IDEA I  
    LEFT JOIN 
        ACCT2 A2 ON A2.IDEA_REF=I.REFERENCE
) as COMB
GROUP BY 
    COMB.SL
```